# How to merge files for N number of days using U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

I want to merge the data from 7 days of files and perform some operation on them using U-SQL.
The folder structure on ADLS - /sample/data/YYYY/MM/DD.1.csv
For e.g. Today is 03/01/2018 (DD/MM/YYYY) then I want to pick the data from 27/12/2017 to 02/01/2018.

In U-SQL how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use virtual columns in your file path.
For example:

```
 DECLARE @path = "/sample/data/{FileDate:yyyy}/{FileDate:MM}/{FileDate:dd}.1.csv
 DECLARE @startDate = new DateTime(2017,12,27);
 DECLARE @endDate = new DateTime(2018,01,02);

 @data = EXTRACT 
     column1 string,
    column2 string,
    FileDate DateTime
    from @path
USING Extractors.Csv(); //or which extractor you are using


OUTPUT(
SELECT * FROM @data
WHERE FileDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
TO "/sample/data/appended.csv
USING Outputters.Text(delimiter : ';', outputHeader : true); //output this in your csv file
```

This code should extract you all data in your date range. 
P.S. I am not sure just if i wrote good file name, check that. 
Hope this will help you. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/extract-expression-u-sql) you can find documentation about virtual columns.

Comment: Dragan, thanks for the  reply. Let me try that out. Actually what I want to do is to process last rolling 7 days of data. So lets say today is 03/01/2018 so as per your code it will pick data from 27/12/2017 to 02/01/2018 but if out of those 7 days if any of the file is missing then it will go back to previous day's file. That is if the file for 01/01/2018 is not present then it will pick files from 26/12/2017 so at any given point it will need 7 days of files.

Comment: This will pick all files from a defined time period. If I understood you, you want if there is no file in some day to decrease startdate, so it will not be 27/12 it will be 26/12. The thing is you don't have control flows in USQL, there is a FILE.EXISTS function but you don't have IF/ELSE, UNTIL, etc. 
Maybe you can achieve this with the logic app or data factory. 
In both of this integration platforms, you have control flows and function to check if the file exists.

Comment: DraganB, there is an error in your code the EXTRACT can not contain WHERE clause also the USING Extrator is missing in "@data" resultset

Comment: @DragaonB, it works fine but the performance issue is in the first rowset "@data" though we are saying get the data which bounds between two dates but it reads the data which comes under all the folder and not just the range . For example we have data from the month 1 to 11 for the year 2018 and we want to read data from 01/11/2018 to 30/11/2018 but it reads the data from all months and in next resultset it filters out based on the range of dates.